# MySQL Timeout in IO Operation

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, timeout, entity-framework-6

My Visual Studio 2013 web application uses entity framework accessing the database on a remote MySQL server. The application was working fine but all of a sudden it started showing "MySQL Timeout in IO Operation" for all my sql operations. Nothing has changed in the query or the tables. I can access the remote database using mysql workbench fine.

There is no specific code that does this exception it's just any simple operation that I do on mysql, here's a sample code:

```
public IList getalltblarticle_source()
{
    return db.tbltitles.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a slow internet connection problem.